# Video stop in WebView

Tags: android, video, webview

My Activity contains webView. Sometimes webView contains video. When watching the video in webView and press the back button, I go on to another Activity, but the video continues to play and I hear the sound of video. How can I solve this problem? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Couple different options:

if you want to completely stop the video, make sure you call `finish()` when clicking back.

You can do that like this on your `Activity`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    this.finish();
}
```

`Activity` will be destroyed and video will stop.

If you want to stop the video but not destroy the activity, edit your question and show some of your code so I can give you more options.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution that works for me: [How to stop youtube video playing in Android webview?](http://How%20to%20stop%20youtube%20video%20playing%20in%20Android%20webview?)

```
mWebView.onPause();
```